# ASP.NET Core 6, where to put dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

All the similar topics I found apply to earlier versions of ASP.NET. When I create a database with the commands `Add-Migration InitialCreate` and `Update-Database`, the database builds up correctly. Unfortunately, I cannot cope with the automatic database creation on launch.

I get this message
[Visual Studio 2022 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYg90.png)

My code looks like this:

DotNet.P001.L07.MainProject > Program.cs

```cs
using DotNet.P001.L14.Database;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DotNet.P001.L07.MainProject;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var AngularCorsPolicy = "_angularCorsPolicy";

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option =>
           option.UseSqlServer(
            builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationContext")
            ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationContext' not found.")));

        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(AngularCorsPolicy, policy =>
            {
                policy.WithOrigins(
                    "https://localhost:44472",
                     "https://localhost:7218"
                    )
                .AllowAnyHeader(); ;
            });
        });

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        var app = builder.Build();
        


        // Create database if it does not exist
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();



        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if(!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors(AngularCorsPolicy);

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

DotNet.P001.L14.Database > ApplicationDbContext.cs

```cs
using DotNet.P001.L14.Database.Entities;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DotNet.P001.L14.Database;
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<MessageEntity>? Message { get; set; }
}
```

DotNet.P001.L14.Database > Entities > MessageEntity.cs

```cs
namespace DotNet.P001.L14.Database.Entities;

public class MessageEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public string? FirstNameAuthor { get; set; }
    public string? LastNameAuthor { get; set; }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
It looks like the code was buggy after all and I need to replace the following snippet:

```cs
ApplicationDbContext dbContext = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

must be replaced with the following:

```cs
using(var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            
            //EnsureDeleted() is an additional option that first deletes an existing database.
            dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted(); 
            dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

        }
```

Prepared based on the article [Apply migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi @kzstack, where did you run on, kestrel or IIS Express? What if you change it by another mode?

Comment: @Rena Both solutions gave an error.